# Take MIN EFF_DT and MAX_CANC_dt from data in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

Schema :

```
TYP|ID|RECORD|SEX|EFF_DT|CANC_DT

DMF|1234567|98765432|M|2011-08-30|9999-12-31
DMF|1234567|98765432|M|2011-04-30|9999-12-31
DMF|1234567|98765432|M|2011-04-30|9999-12-31
```

Suppose i have multiple records like this. I only want to display records that have minimum eff_dt and maximum cancel date.

I only want to display just This 1 record

```
DMF|1234567|98765432|M|2011-04-30|9999-12-31
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get min eff_dt and max canc_dt and use it to filter the relation.Assuming you have a relation A

```
B = GROUP A ALL;
X = FOREACH B GENERATE MIN(A.EFF_DT);
Y = FOREACH B GENERATE MAX(A.CANC_DT);

C = FILTER A BY ((EFF_DT == X.$0) AND (CANC_DT == Y.$0));
D = DISTINCT C;
DUMP D;
```

Comment: Will this work if i have multiple records like this with diffrent minimum eff_dt and max canc_dt ?

Comment: @pd123 try it and see for yourself

Comment: Thanks. Worked. Also figured out a new way too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this data (sample here):

```
DMF|1234567|98765432|M|2011-08-30|9999-12-31
DMF|1234567|98765432|M|2011-04-30|9999-12-31
DMF|1234567|98765432|M|2011-04-30|9999-12-31
DMX|1234567|98765432|M|2011-12-30|9999-12-31
DMX|1234567|98765432|M|2011-04-30|9999-12-31
DMX|1234567|98765432|M|2011-04-01|9999-12-31
```

Perform these steps:

```
-- 1. Read data, if you have not 
 A = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (typ: chararray, id:chararray, record:chararray, sex:chararray, eff_dt:datetime, canc_dt:datetime);

-- 2. Group data by the attribute you like to, in this case it is TYP
grouped = group A by typ;

-- 3. Now, generate MIN/MAX for each group. Also, only keep relevant fields
min_max = foreach grouped generate group, MIN(A.eff_dt) as min_eff_dt, MAX(A.canc_dt) as max_canc_dt;

-- 
dump min_max;
(DMF,2011-04-30T00:00:00.000Z,9999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z)
(DMX,2011-04-01T00:00:00.000Z,9999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z)
```

If you need to, change datetime to charrary.

Note: there are different ways of doing this, what I am showing, except the load step, it produces the desired result in 2 steps: GROUP and FOREACH.